# Сколько существует натуральных чисел, шестнадцатеричная запись которых содержит 6 знаков, не начинается с единицы и заканчивается на AB?

Tags: python, комбинаторика, перебор

> Сколько существует натуральных чисел, шестнадцатеричная запись которых содержит 6 знаков, не начинается с единицы и заканчивается на AB?
> Ответ: 57344

Мой код:

```
import itertools

l = list(itertools.product('0123456789abcdef', repeat=6))
new = []

for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i][0] not in '01' and l[i][-1] in 'ab':
        new.append(l[i])

print(len(new))
```

Ошибка в том, что программа выдает неверный ответ. И мне хотелось бы понять, как правильно ее решать на питоне?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что программа выдает неверный ответ. И мне хотелось бы понять, как правильно ее решать на питоне. Но если вы знаете логический способ решения, буду рада, если вы им поделитесь)

Comment: Первый символ не может быть `0` (иначе это не 6-значное число), и `1` (по условию), значит может быть только от `2` до `F` - это 14 вариантов. Второй-Третий-Четвертый могут быть от `0` до `F` - это 16 вариантов. Пятый и Шестой могут быть только `A` и `B` (по условию). Итого 14 * 16 * 16 * 16 * 1 * 1 = 57344

Comment: заканчивается на AB — это не то же самое что «заканчивается на A или B» как написано у вас в коде. И вообще это не задача на программирование, а задача на тупо посчитать

Answer (score 1):

Это не задача на программирование, а задача на просто посчитать:

Первый символ не может быть `0` (иначе это не 6-значное число), и `1` (по условию), значит может быть только от `2` до `F` - это 14 вариантов. Второй-Третий-Четвертый могут быть от `0` до `F` - это по 16 вариантов. Пятый и Шестой могут быть только `A` и `B` (по условию). Итого 14 * 16 * 16 * 16 * 1 * 1 = 57344